# Copying text to clipboard leads to crash on parallel tests execution on emulators

Tags: android, multithreading, appium, adb, appium-android

Running test on appium android on several emulators. Using ThreadLocal to separate driver instances.
Faced with problem when one of emulators always crashes on the same step.

After investigating I came to the conclusion that the reason is clipboard. One emulator clicks on the clipboard field and after some time the second do the same and crashes.

Java exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
```

Adb logs:

```
*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: beginBroadcast() called while already in a broadcast
    at android.os.RemoteCallbackList.beginBroadcast(RemoteCallbackList.java:241)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService.setPrimaryClipInternal(ClipboardService.java:583)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService$1.onHostClipboardUpdated(ClipboardService.java:205)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.HostClipboardMonitor.run(ClipboardService.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

So my question is:

1. Whether it is possible to disable saving anything to clipboard using adb or appium command?
2. Whether it is possible to clear it so it would be a kind of resetting?
3. Or maybe there is a decision in the multithreading area?
4. Any other ways?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by resetting the clipboard right after anything was placed in it. Means immediately after clicking on the field.

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(null), null);
```

Comment: Where did you add this?